# Динамически изменять "id" и "label for" у инпутов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте!

Вопрос следующий...

Как мне автоматически изменять `id` и `label for` у инпутов?

Например

```
<input type="radio" id="id1">
<label for="id1"></label>

<input type="radio" id="id2">
<label for="id2"></label>
```

**Прошу обратить внимание, что input находиться не внутри label, если это имеет значение**

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под словом "автоматически"?

Comment: предполагаю имел ввиду автосвязку их между собой

Comment: ну так в чем проблемы, непонятно. берете и изменяете)  только для label пишите не input label (или label input), а input next....... но в целом непонятно что вы хотите менять, как и для чего

Comment: Мне необходимо, чтобы у каждого последующего инпута был уникальный id, например цифра дописывалась на конце.

Comment: так берите количество инпутов (length), добавляйте к значению единицу и записывайте в атрибут `id` созданного инпута. непонятны проблемы опять

Comment: Как понять количество?  Заранее количество инпутов не известно, инпуты создаются CMS для каждого товара.  Собственно я и спрашиваю как добавить к значению единицу ))

Comment: я же написал ... `length`........`$('input[type=radio]').length` - их количество

Comment: Я верстаю каталог товаров,  сверстал один товар (у него 3 инпута), после того как я закину эту верстку в CMS, у меня сама CMS будет добавлять новый товар беря мою верстку за шаблон для товара, соответсвенно у каждого нового товара будут одни и те же id для инпутов.  Поэтому я спрашиваю ка мне их (инпуты )изменять с добавлением каждого нового товара

Comment: Господа,ниужели никто не поможет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#add-field').on('click', function(){
  var nextId = $('input[type=checkbox]').length + 1;
  
  $('#wrapper').append('<input type="checkbox" id="id' + (nextId) + '"><label for="id' + nextId + '">Checkbox ' + nextId + '</label>');
});
```

```css
label:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="checkbox" id="id1">
  <label for="id1">Checkbox 1</label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="id2">
  <label for="id2">Checkbox 2</label>  
</div>

<button id="add-field">Добавить</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!  Очень выручили!

Answer (score 0):

Это довольно странно, лучше генерировать сразу нормальные `ID`, но...

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('label[for]')).forEach(l => {
  let id = l.getAttribute('for'),
      inp = document.querySelector(`#${id}`),
      newID = id + '1'; // Главное - не генерируйте для ВСЕХ элементов один ID; один раунд - один ID
      
  if(inp)
    l.setAttribute('for', newID), inp.setAttribute('id', newID);
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="id1">
<label for="id1">Checkbox 1</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="id2">
<label for="id2">Checkbox 2</label>
```

Comment: Код Ваш вставил, но ничего не произошло ))

Comment: @АлексейЯрыгин, как "вставил"? Вы же понимаете что это пример, а не решение для "скопировать - вставить"? В сниппете работает.